# vb6 control listview eliminar borde punteado

Tags: vb6

Estoy modificando una aplicación antigua de mi trabajo. Mediante winsock y  listview muestro una serie de impresoras y básicamente su estado. Me está complicando un recuadro punteado alrededor del 1er item del listview, no doy con la forma de evitarlo. La idea es que es solo un informe visual, no necesito interactuar con las filas. Alguna idea de como hacer desaparecer el borde  ?
Adjunto fragmento donde configuro el listview y una imagen del problema. Gracias !!!

```html
    With ListView1
        .ColumnHeaders.Clear
        .ListItems.Clear
        .View = lvwReport
        .SmallIcons = ImageList1
        .MultiSelect = False
        .HideSelection = True
        .SortKey = 0
        .SortOrder = lvwAscending
        .Sorted = True
        Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "        Equipo", 2510)
        Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "        Estado", 2510)
        Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "Fecha reporte", 3320, lvwColumnCenter)
        Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "Tickets", 1315, lvwColumnCenter)
    End With
```

[image: En la primera fila 1er item se ve el recuadro, como si tuviera el foco]

Answer (score 0):

Hay una property del ListView, que se llama algo así como **FullRowSelect**, la seteas en true y eso cambia el comportamiento a uno distinto que no tiene ese rectángulo

Comment: Hola amigo, probé lo que dices, encontré info sobre esto e hice la llamada via api. Ahora en vez de la linea punteada sobre el item me hace una linea continua sobre todo el row . Queda apenas mejor que antes, pero necesito eliminar esa linea punteada.

Comment: Entiendo.
Sabes, yo solía emplear mucho listview en los 2000, y no tengo recuerdo de los puntos, ni tampoco de quitarlos, sé que tambien los habría querido eliminar.

También los usé siempre con view igual a Report, la única diferencia es que yo utilizaba iconos de 16 px, no estoy bien seguro, pero me dá la impresión que los íconos mayores al tamaño inicial la fila , pudieran haber provocado esa redefinición.

Intenta setear.GridLines = True solo por ver que sucede, y otro sería que trataras de ejectuar, sin los íconos, incluso en fullRow = false como tenías antes, para arrojar pistas

Comment: ¿HotTracking le tienes en false?

Answer (score 0):

Hace muchos años que no toco VB6, así que no se si te servirá, pero en unos foros de Visual Basic (http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?475494-RESOLVED-Remove-selection-highlight-from-listbox-and-listview) recomendaban poner la propiedad `SelectedItem` a `Nothing`. Parece que les funcionaba.
Otros además proponían añadir `ListIndex = -1`

Tu código quedaría así con el cambio.

```
With ListView1
    .ColumnHeaders.Clear
    .ListItems.Clear
    .View = lvwReport
    .SmallIcons = ImageList1
    .MultiSelect = False
    .HideSelection = True
    .SortKey = 0
    .SortOrder = lvwAscending
    .Sorted = True
    Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "        Equipo", 2510)
    Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "        Estado", 2510)
    Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "Fecha reporte", 3320, lvwColumnCenter)
    Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "Tickets", 1315, lvwColumnCenter)
    .SelectedItem = Nothing
    .ListIndex = -1
End With
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: he probado este código.  listindex no es aceptado por el listview pero agregué lo demás. No ha resultado, no ha cambiado nada.

Comment: Lo siento, por los comentarios parecía que había funcionado.